# Intent without context

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I have an intent thats designed to be a POSSIBLE follow up intent. I don't want to assign it as a follow up because I want it to be used as an entry point. So for my parameters I assign the default value to the value passed in by the context.

And that works! As a follow up it works great and the context is passed through. However when I try any of the phrases without the context it goes to the "Default Fallback Intent."

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, I can leave the input context in Dialogflow blank and assign the value context as a default value of a parameter. As long as the context has been created from a previous intent it's all good. Now if you have a context it will use the context as a parameter, and if not it will you can prompt the user for a parameter. (Which you should export)